# Reusing drawable from different density

Tags: android

suppose I have xh and medium density folders and I want to use the image located in the the medium folder while running an xh density device,is it possible? can I make I reference from one folder to the other ?

Comment: You can do that through aliases but those density folders are there for a reason and I don't see a scenario where you'll benefit from that.

Comment: Me no, but memory and apk size will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In api 15 and above you can use the following function:

[`getResources().getDrawableForDensity(id, density)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawableForDensity%28int,%20int%29)

The second argument should be one of the `DisplayMetric`s. In your case use [DENSITY_MEDIUM](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_MEDIUM)